# UITapGesture not arriving at UICollectionView (collection view is subview of TableViewCell)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableViewCell->contentView that contains a UICollectionView with a HorizontalFlowLayout.

The TableViewCell is the delegate and datasource for the UICollectionView.

All of the panning behavior works as expected.  Panning up / down will scroll the table view.  Panning left / right on a table cell will scroll the UICollectionView.

However, **TAPPING** on the table cells does NOT get passed along to the UICollectionView.

I know this because the code in:

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```

is never called.

I tried manually tweaking the delegates for the UITableView gesture recognizers like so:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // connect our gesture handlers so we stop the tableView from grabbing taps
    for (UIGestureRecognizer* gr in playerTable.gestureRecognizers) {
        if (![gr isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
            [gr setDelegate:self];
        }
    }
}

#pragma GestureRecognizer delegate
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    return NO;
}
```

but that didn't work either.

What is the best way to ensure that the TapGesture is passed down to the UICollectionView and thus I can 'select' a cell?

**PS.** I did look at various similar tickets, but couldn't find a solution that applied.  Definitely wouldn't doubt that it is already here... just didn't see it.

Comment: Is your table view calling the delegate-method shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:? In that case that might be your problem that the table view gets the touch instead. The issue here is nested scrollViews, which can sometimes be complicated. I will return to my ponder cave for further thought-gathering.

Comment: I hadn't actually connected the delegate yet, but I can and see.  I figured if I wasn't trapping for highlight or select it would pass through.  Let me know what your cave illuminates. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a face palm issue... had another gesture recognizer on top of everything else that was grabbing the taps.  Works perfectly as expected without that.

Answer (score 0):

You should not set the UITableViewCell as the delegate but whatever view controller that is hosting the UITableView. [This](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell) is a great tutorial.

Comment: I actually saw that tutorial.  I see where he says it is 'very very bad' but not where it is explained why.  Could you explain what is bad about this situation, it seems to work just fine (outside of the touch issue)

Comment: Because the UITableViewCell's concern is not to populate data into a collection view. It not clean. Si far you have only found the gesture issue but if you continue to play with it you will find other unexpected behavior.

Comment: Hmm, I can see that but still not sure that I am convinced.  The tap issue was completely unrelated and my fault, it was not due to a structural issue.  A TableCell's concern is to populate data into that table cell, if that cell includes a collection view, then it should also handle that, no?  I would argue the code locality is much better in this setup that having the top level controller be the data source for the embedded collection views.